# weekly max count record in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

table test has column id,created_date,sal and data like below:

| ID | create_date | sal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20-JAN-2021 | 5000 |
| 2 | 20-JAN-2021 | 6000 |
| 3 | 19 -JAN- 2021 | 4000 |

we have data like this for each date.

I pick the each day record count using below query:

```
select count(*) ,create_date from test
group by create_date desc
order by 2 desc;
```

I want output for max record count for a weekly basis:

| count(*) | create_date |
| --- | --- |
| 500 | 20 - JAN-2021 |
| 600 | 10 - JAN - 2021 |
| 300 | 1 - JAN - 2021 |

Please suggest.

like this.

Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `trunc` date to iso week and use two level grouping as follows:

```
Select max(cnt) as max_cnt, 
       trunc(create_date,'IW') as week_start_date
  From
    (select count(*) as cnt, 
            create_date
       from test
      Group by create_date )
group by trunc(create_date,'IW') 
order by 2 desc;
```

If you want the date also then you need to use analytical function as dollows:

```
Select * from
     (select count(*) as cnt, 
            create_date,
            Row_number() over (partition by trunc(create_date,'IW') 
                               order by count(*) desc) as rn
       from test
      Group by create_date) t
Where rn = 1
```

Comment: this query return max on weekly basis but date is not showing correctly. for Ex:  for week 25jan to 30 jan max record is available for 28th JAN but its showing date as 25 JAN.

Comment: It will show week start date. Do you want the date of max count day? See the updated answer.

Comment: yes..the exact date which have max count for that week